# How to configure nginx to redirect to https ... except for one directory

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https, lets-encrypt

I'm setting up an nginx webserver to support multiple virtual hosts. Following best practice, I want any http:// request to be redirected to the equivalent https://.

That much is straightforward, but I want to have one exception: any request for any file under /.well-known/ should be served as http, without the https redirect. Anyone who's worked with LetsEncrypt will recognize the '.well-known' directory as the place that LetsEncrypt looks for verification files. These *must* be served over HTTP.

So far, I have a configuration file for 'default' that looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    root /var/www/default/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ^~ /.well-known/ {
        allow all;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Then, for each virtual host, I have a separate file that looks like:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myexamplevirtualhost.com;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    # lots more SSL-related stuff
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myexamplevirtualhost.com;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    location /.well-known/ { }
}
```

If I request, for example, `http://myexamplevirtualhost.com/`, I get redirected to `https://myexamplevirtualhost.com/` -- which is what I want. Similarly, a direct request for `https://myexamplevirtualhost.com/` works as intended.

However, if I try: `http://myexamplevirtualhost.com/.well-known/foo123`, instead of the server simply serving up `http://myexamplevirtualhost.com/.well-known/foo123` (which is the goal), it does a redirect to `https://myexamplevirtualhost.com/.well-known/foo123`.

I've tried a lot of different things -- changing the order of location rules, etc. -- but I still can't seem to get the behaviour I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have HTTP Strict Transport Security?

Comment: Yes, the server block for the individual domains includes:

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000
    
Hmm. That might be my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) enabled you won't be able to "turn off" https for certain pages, since https will be forced for the whole domain. You might be able to use some convoluted setup of HTTP 302 redirects to make this work, but I'm not sure why you would want to. Let's Encrypt will have no trouble renewing certs if your .well-known directory is served over HTTPS.

Comment: I believe that the use of HSTS is indeed the issue, as spotted by you and Richard Smith.

Comment: Won't Lets Encrypt have problem when .well-known is server over HTTPS with expired certificate thougth?

Comment: @gorn it should ignore the expired certificate. See https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#http-01-challenge